# "La logique métier" or "le logique métier" ?

Tags: grammaire, sens

I have this confusion situation when I was writing a report basically the word "logique" is female so we should write "La logique" but when we add the word "métier" which is a male we have a "groupe nominal" male noun,
According to reverso and Microsoft words "le logique métier" is the correct forme, but it seems to be very weird to hear "le logique métier".
What do you think?

Comment: In "le logique métier", logique is an adjective, modifier of métier. It can be rephrased "le métier logique." However, this is no what you want. You want something along the lines of "la logique du métier." Therefore, "la" is correct.

Comment: @MorganFR D'ailleurs, est-ce que cette pratique porte un nom ? Est-ce la même figure de style dans "je suis développeur web" ?

Comment: @SimonDéchamps Sûrement, mais je ne le connais pas. Ce qui est sûr c'est que c'est une sorte d'expansion du nom. Le nom agit alors comme un adjectif, mais il reste un nom.

Comment: @SimonDéchamps I think it is a "complément du nom", or at least it acts like one.

Comment: Le logique métier is a grammar mistake in French. It is wrong. La logique DU métier. Often, in modern corporate French, one leaves out a de here or there to shorten sentences. So, you can say: la logique métier et every French person knows that means: la logique DU métier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You picked it right but Reverso and MS Word did not (they considered *logique* to be an adjective, while it is a noun is that case.

*"La logique métier"* could be expanded to *"la logique **du** métier"*, where it is obvious that both *logique* and *métier* are nouns. In that sense, it is identical to the English *"the job logics"*. Also, as pointed out in comments, *"je suis développeur web"* (in English *"I am a web developer"*) falls in the same category: *"je suis développeur **pour le** web"*.

Answer (score 9):

Your confusion may come from the fact that "Logique" can be used as a noun or an adjective in french. But remember, "La bleue voiture" (adj. before noun) is wrong in french it should be "La voiture bleue". "Logique" can be an adjective for feminin noun ("*La solution logique*") or masculin noun ("*Le résultat logique*", "*Le métier logique*"...) but you must respect [the french way of using adjective](http://french.about.com/od/grammar/a/adjectives_4.htm) ie: most of the time adjectifs come after nouns. You can't say "Le logique métier" in this order.

If you're talking about the computer term "business logic" (as in "*separate an application's business logic from the aspects of the technical implementation*") it's indeed "**la logique métier**" in french because "logique" is not an adjective but a noun in this case.

Comment: Putting the adjective before the noun is NOT ungrammatical, and often used in an elevated register. And sometimes, it is even preferable to use the adjective before the noun, e.g. "Mon bel amour."

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I clarified my answer accordingly.

Comment: How did you clarify it? "La bleue voiture" is NOT wrong.

Comment: At first it may not have been clear in my answer that there was a lot of exceptions where adj before noun is ok to use. But if you think that saying "la bleue voiture" is ok, then we disagree. We're not talking about fine poetry or trying to be clever here. In a report or anything not related to poetry, it sounds strange, excessively high register, and will make OP looks foolish.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I'm just wondering why Microsoft word, reverso, scribens and cordial mark la logique métier as wrong synthax   "logique métier est un groupe nominal masculin"!!!
You can see the general [role here](http://www.scribens.fr/Exp/Accords/AccordGeneralNomAdj.html)

Comment: I don't know.  I think it's more of an IT question on syntax checkers at this point. Syntax checkers are hard to program and errors are not impossible. But the same error on 4 of them still raise questions... Wild guess here : it migth be because "la logique métier" is an (uncommon?) IT term, or deemed an anglicism ? Let's see what other answers bring to the table.

Answer (score 1):

> La logique métier
>
> La logique du métier

L'article « du » est escamoté ( à tort, mais c'est devenu l'usage)

> La logique métier :

Toutes/Les règles qui articulent/régentent un métier.

Un métier peut être une activité au sein d'une société : « vendeur », d'un atelier : « soudeur », au sein d'une petite entreprise: « cordonnier » - « réparation de chaussure. »